# Kendo UI Inline grid not receiving Date Fields but other fields value getting in controller

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, inline-editing

I have used Kendo UI grid with inline editing, all filed received in controller but date field not receiving why?

This is my code, please help me

Grid---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#orders-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CustomerList", "Customer"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CustomerAdd", "Customer"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url:"@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CustomerUpdate", "Customer"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CustomerDelete", "Customer"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },

                            },

                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors",
                                model: {
                                    id: "Id",
                                    fields: {
                                        stfName: { editable: true, type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                                        Id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                                        stmName: { editable: true, type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                                        dtdob: { editable: true, type: "Date",format : "dd/MMM/yyyy", validation: { required: true } },
                                        strefName: { editable: true, type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            requestEnd: function (e) {
                                if (e.type == "create" || e.type == "update") {
                                    this.read();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                //display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                // Cancel the changes
                                this.cancelChanges();
                            },
                            pageSize: 10,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: [10]
                        }, //scrollable: false,
                        // dataBound: onDataBound,
                        sortable: true,
                        scrollable: {
                            virtual: true
                        },
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        editable: {
                            confirmation: false,
                            mode: "inline"
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "Id",
                                title: "ID",
                                width: 50
                            },{
                                field: "stfName",
                                title: "First Name",
                                //attributes: { "class": "upper" },
                                width: 200
                            },
                                {
                                    field: "dtdob",
                                    title: "D.O.B.",
                                    //editor: customDateEditor,
                                    type: "Date",
                                    template: "#=kendo.toString(dtdob,'dd/MMM/yyyy')#",
                                    //template: '<input type="date" name="dtdob" />',
                                   width: 200,
                                   //parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"]

                                },
                                {
                                    field: "strefName",
                                    title: "Reference",
                                    width: 200
                                },
                            {
                            command: [{
                                name: "edit",
                                text: "Edit"
                            }, {
                                name: "destroy",
                                text: "Delete"
                    }],
                       width: 200,
                    filterable: true
                    }]
                    });

                    var customDateEditor = function (container, options) {
                        $('<input />')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoDatePicker({
                                format: "dd/MMM/yyyy"
                            });
                    };
                    });
--model
```

public partial class tblCustomer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string stfName { get; set; }
            public DateTime dtdob { get; set; }
           }
        }

```
Controller----

    public ActionResult CustomerUpdate(tblCustomer model) <-All Value receive  in model except date field dtdob
            {
    }

I have check in firebug there is ajax call and all fields pass properly event date too, but not receiving in controller why?

Regards,
Vinit Patel
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the link given below. It does have couple of solutions for the issue you are fixing. Please revert if the issue persists.

[Passing dates from Kendo UI to ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.falafel.com/passing-dates-kendo-ui-aspnet/)